# pdftk move page 1 to the end

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I am looking for the correct script to move the first page to the end of a PDF file, regardless of how many pages the file has. It is unknown how many pages will be in each file but we want to move the cover page to the end.

The command:

```
pdftk.exe orig.pdf cat end-1 output out.pdf
```

just reverses the order.

I am sure this is pretty easy but I am knew to this.

Comment: try `pdftk orig.pdf cat 2-end 1 output out.pdf`

Comment: @steeldriver thank you for your reply. when I try that I get "Unexpected text in page range end"

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce that - perhaps your pdftk version is different from mine (in particular, `pdftk.exe` suggests you are using a Windows version of some sort)

Comment: Sorry @steeldriver your first solution worked perfectly. I had omitted the output statement when replacing the output file name. Appreciate the help here.

Comment: @steeldriver I came across this question. It seems that your answer in the comment solved the OP's problem. Do you mind adding it as a proper answer?

Answer (score 0):

As [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) suggests in their [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313062/pdftk-move-page-1-to-the-end#comment2235224_1313062), you can run:

```
pdftk orig.pdf cat 2-end 1 output out.pdf
```